# How can I test for bivariate normality using Shapiro-Wilk test in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I've computed the Pearson correlation coefficient between two lists and am now trying to verify whether these two data sets are normally distributed in order to ascertain the validity of the the correlation.

From What I've read in the documentation, I should be able to use multivariate data with The ShapiroWilkTest function, but so far I have been unable to obtain an output. I do not receive an error, but the process hangs seemingly indefinitely. I am, however, able to obtain an output with univariate Shapiro-Wilk tests of either my dependent or independent variable almost instantly.

Here's what I've tried:

```
data1 = {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7}
data2 = {y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7}
ShapiroWilkTest[{data1,data2}]
```

Comment: As far as I know, the *validity* of the correlation has nothing to do with whether or not the two lists are normally distributed. Perhaps you mean the validity of the calculation of the significance of the correlation?

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes you're right, I could have phrased that more clearly. I wanted to test for normality as it is one of the assumptions of the Pearson correlation coefficient (along with linearity and homoscedasticity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you by chance tried:

```
ShapiroWilkTest[Transpose@{data1,data2}]
```

I don't have that function, so I have no idea of the result.

Comment: I've got The Fonz' touch today.  [SWAG](http://www.acronymfinder.com/SWAG.html) all the way.

Comment: "Special Warfare Group (Philippine Navy)"?

Comment: @Brett:  "sure kid, why not" ;-)